# Meaning of sanskirt sentence

Tags: scripture

Hello can someone tell me meaning:
रोलम्बः rolambaḥ A bee; महानेवालम्बो हरिनयनरोलम्बवरयोः Lakṣmīlaharī 19; तस्या रोलम्बावली केशजालम् Dk.; Bv.1.118.
Its clear that it relates to some form of godess.